# Opening A Webroswer from a textbox with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, search, textbox, inputbox

I'm having trouble with using variables in a string. I'm trying to open a web browser as a search engine using google, like this;

```
Dim webAddress As String = "https://www.google.com/webhp#q=TextBox1.Text"
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

How can I open googles search engine by entering text into a text field and hitting a button?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim engine As String
Dim search As String
Dim url As String
engine = CStr("https://www.google.com/webhp#q=")
search = TextBox1.Text
url = api + arg
Process.Start(url)
```

Comment: Please! Don't use `+` when concatenating strings! Use the ampersand instead (`&`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    Dim webAddress As String = String.Format("https://www.google.com/webhp#q={0}", TextBox1.Text)
    Process.Start(webAddress)
```